# A commutative square yields 6 homotopy cofiber sequences?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

$\require{AMScd}$
Let $M$ be a pointed model category, consider a commutative square
$$
\begin{CD}
X' @> f' >> Y'\\
@Vu_0VV  @VVu_1V \\
X @>> f > Y,
\end{CD}
$$
taking the homotopy cofiber of the four maps give a diagram as follows
$$
\begin{CD}
X' @> f' >> Y'@> g' >> C'\\
@Vu_0VV  @VVu_1V @VVu_2V\\
X @>> f > Y@>> g > C\\
@Vv_0VV  @VVv_1V\\
X'' @> f'' >> Y'',
\end{CD}
$$
taking further the homotopy cofiber of $f''$ gives a commutative diagram like this:
$$
\begin{CD}
X' @> f' >> Y'@> g' >> C'\\
@Vu_0VV  @VVu_1V @VVu_2V\\
X @>> f > Y@>> g > C\\
@Vv_0VV  @VVv_1V @VVv_2V\\
X'' @> f'' >> Y''@> g'' >> C''.
\end{CD}
$$
My question is

> Does the right vertical also form a homotopy cofiber sequence so that in the end we get 6 homotopy cofiber sequences (which means in the second diagram, we can take the same object as the homotopy cofiber of both $f''$ and $u_2$)?

Comment: Yes. It's more clear if you describe $C''$ as follows: let $Z$ be the homotopy pushout of the square without $Y$; then $C''$ is the cofiber of the map $Z \to Y$.

Comment: There's also a nice proof which says that the construction of $C''$ from a square is (homotopically) left adjoint to the functor $\mathcal{M} \to \mathrm{Fun}(\square, \mathcal{M})$ which sends $m$ to the square with $Y''=m$ and all the others $0$. (This is a special case of a more general fact for cubical diagrams which I learned from a paper of Antolín-Camarena-Barthel here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7271.pdf)

Comment: I don't know how to see that the map (f'', g'') then form a homotopy cofiber sequence if we define C'' as you did. Could you explain the point, or even better, expand a little of your comment to an answer? And in your second comment, do you mean that sends an object m to the square with Y'=m, not Y''?

Comment: I actually meant Y! Sorry. And I’ll try to come back and write more when I have time.